# Wcf Http and Https

Tags: wcf, http, iis-7, https

Help please!!

I had the following set up working perfectly:-

1. WCF Service Library hosted in web site on local IIS 7
2. Silverlight Application on a web site on local IIS 7 using above services

The solution I am writing is for intranet and not internet use, however I have been told by my bosses that it needs to be over Https. I am using Windows Authentication.

Below is a chunk of the config file for one of the service endpoints (changed to remove company info etc):-

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="stdHttpBehavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary.StaticDataService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="windowsHttpBinding"
      name="StaticDataService" contract="WcfServiceLibrary.ServiceContracts.IStaticDataService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/WcfServiceLibrary/StaticDataService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="stdHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

To experiment with Https I created a 'Self-Signed Certificate'. I then added https to the Default Web Site bindings and changed the two web sites to require SSL and also changed the relvant URIs in the config files. I managed to get this to work but now I want to go back to standard Http and finish the project in that mode as it was easier to work with. I changed all the settings back (and I have checked these extremely carefully).

Now I get this error if I try to downoad the Service definition in the Silverlight project: -

'Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].'

If I put back the certificate and binding in IIS. The Service definition appears to download OK, however it references an https URI and therefore none of the actual service calls work as they are http adresses!

I tried adding a new web site to host the service but got the same errors.

I have been trying to solve this for the last couple of days but cannot find an answer. It seems as though there is a hidden reference somewhere and not in my project as it continued with a new web site added to IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use SSL over HTTP under Basic HTTP binding, you need to switch your endpoint to use Transport-level security. In your case you will also want to indicate the client credential type:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="windowsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        <message />
      </security>
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem but in reverse. I did change the security mode to Transport when I set up for Https but I did not change it back to TransportWithCredentialOnly because I thought that Transport was allowed for either Http or Https. It seems that Transport requires Https and therefore fails, telling you it cannot find Https even when you have not set Https endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem obvious, but did you **change the security mode** on the `windowsHttpBinding` binding configuration to `BasicHttpSecurityMode.None`?

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="windowsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Related resources:**

- [Transport Security Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx)
- [BasicHttpSecurityMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpsecuritymode.aspx)

Comment: Whe I used Http security mode TransportWithCredentialOnly it worked. For Https I changed to Transport. I mistakenly thought that Transport was allowed for Http also and didn't change it back.